# Create a carousel with automovement - issue with working with time/pause all the time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a sort of a multi element carousel:

I implemented left and right but I have problems with auto:

```
function addCarouselListener() {
            data.forEach(function (carousel) {
                carousel.previous.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);
                carousel.next.addEventListener('click', moveRight);
            });
        }


        function autoslide() {
            var max =10, visible=6, count=visible;
            max = 10

            while (count < max) {
              moveRight();
                count +=1;
            }

           if (count=max)  // go back
            while(count > visible) { 
            moveLeft( )
            count -=1;
```

}

First this is not really working always, I need to always work and have a timer.
Second, I need to pause if the user click on left,right(previous/next).

Please don't send me links to already done scripts, because I want to understand, plus I need something more custom.

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand, are you using some javascript library? What is your actual problem? The code you posted does not do much of anything, I'm afraid nobody can help you with this minimal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can clearly tell you that this line doesn't work as you'd expect :

`if (count = max)`

To compare equality between two variables you must use `==` or `===` if you'd like to also compare their type.

Also if you just do that like this, the slider will loop so fast that your browser will probably crash.

You want to use `setInterval()`

Here is a simple not-tested example :

```
var direction = 'right'
var current_position = 0
var max = 10
var delay = 500
var timer = false

function move_slider(){
    if(direction == 'right')
        current_position += 1
    if(direction == 'left')
        current_position -= 1

    // move the slider
}

function auto_slide(){
    console.log(current_position, direction)
    move_slider()

    if(current_position <= 0)
        direction = 'right'
    if(current_position >= max)
        direction = 'left'
}

function set_auto_mode(){
  timer = window.setInterval(auto_slide, delay) 
}

function unset_auto_mode(){
  window.clearInterval(timer)
  timer = false
}
```